# AngularJS string url concat form data

Tags: angularjs, expression, string-concatenation

I am trying to send form data from a contact form to a web service by concat string method. I have made a controller who looks like this:

```
// contact controller
eventApp.controller('contactController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.obj = {
        val1: 'personName',
        val2: 'email',
        val3: 'subject',
        val4: 'emailMessage'
    };
    $scope.sendMessage = function(obj) {
        var string = '#/path/' + $scope[obj.val1] + '/' + $scope[obj.val2] + '/' + $scope[obj.val3] + '/' + $scope[obj.val4];
        //$scope.debug.val = string;
        console.log(obj);
    };
}]);
```

How do I make it possible to fill in input values for the values 'personName', 'email', 'subject' and 'emailMessage' like 'John', 'john@email.com', 'webservice' and 'Hello!'? Should I use expressions?

In the DOM console I get an object answer like this when I tap the send button:

```
Object {val1: "personName", val2: "email", val3: "subject", val4: "emailMessage"}
```

My HTML is looking like this:

```
<!-- partial-contact.html -->
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
    <div id="form-container">
        <!-- Contact Heading -->
        <div class="page-header text-center">
            <h1><i class="fa fa-comment"></i> Kontakt</h1>
            <p>Ved spørsmål skriv ein epost i kontaktskjemaet under.</p>
        </div>
        <!-- Form -->
        <!-- use ng-submit to catch the form submission and use our Angular function -->
        <form id="contactForm" name="contactForm" novalidate ng-submit="contactForm()" ng-controller="contactController" method="post">
        <!-- Name -->
        <div class="input-group margin-bottom-sm">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
            <input id="personName" class="form-control" type="text" name="personName" ng-model="contactData.personName" placeholder="Namn *" required />
        </div>
        <!-- Email -->
        <div class="input-group margin-bottom-sm">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-fw"></i></span>
            <input id="email" class="form-control" type="email" name="email" ng-model="contactData.email" placeholder="Epost *" required />
        </div>
        <!-- Subject -->
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-info"></i></span>
            <input id="subject" class="form-control" type="text" name="subject" ng-model="contactData.subject" placeholder="Emne *" required />
        </div>
        <!-- Email Message & Button -->
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <!-- Email Message -->
                <textarea id="emailMessage" type="text" class="form-control" name="emailMessage" ng-model="contactData.emailMessage" ng-minlength=10 ng-maxlength=300 placeholder="Melding..." required></textarea>
                <!-- Button -->
                <button id="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="sendMessage(obj)"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Instead of `var string = '#/path/' + $scope[obj.val1] + '/' + $scope[obj.val2] + '/' + $scope[obj.val3] + '/' + $scope[obj.val4];` try `var string = '#/path/' + $scope.obj.val1. + '/' ....`

Answer (score 0):

`contactData` is your object in the controller scope holding the data.

use `$scope.contactData[obj.val1]` instead of `$scope[obj.val1]`